# vmlinuz file for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse

How do I look for the `vmlinuz` file for Ubuntu from SUSE. I try: `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` then `cd /boot`, but I don't see the `vmlinuz` file for Ubuntu. Where is it? The `/boot` directory is empty.

Comment: did you mean "The /boot directory is empty"?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC on Ubuntu /boot by default gets it's own partition. You could try check

```
# sudo cfdisk
```

the line looking somewhat like the following should be your /boot

```
sda1        Boot        Primary   Linux ext3                       20530.30
```

or with

```
# sudo fdisk -l
```

it should look kind of like this

```
/dev/sda1   *           1        2496    20049088+  83  Linux
```

you notice the flag "Boot" set which means that this is the partition BIOS tries to load the bootloader from... under normal circumstances this should be the /boot partition.

Comment: "Ubuntu /boot by default gets it's own partition" - No. Unless it's strictly necessary, the regular installer will not do this unless you tell it to use `/` on an LVM LV for example. But yes, probably resides on a different partition in this case.